# PHP Calling To Object From Another Object

Tags: php, oop

I've been programming mainly with JAVA and have written procedural programs in PHP, but now I'm try to write some OOP bases programs in PHP and I'm facing a problem.
I've got two files , `Zoo.php` and `Dog.php` , each contains a class.

**Dog.php:**

```
<?php
class Dog {
     private $name;
     private $color;

     public function __construct($name,$color) {
         $this->name = $name;
         $this->color = $color;
     }

     public function getName(){
         return $this->name;
     }

     public function getColor(){
         return $this->color;
     }
}
```

And **Zoo.php**:

```
<?php

class Zoo {
    private $name;
    private $dogs;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $dogs = array();
    }

    public function addDog($dogName,$dogColor){
        $dog = new Dog($dogName,$dogColor);
        array_push($this->dogs,$dog);
    }

    public function getAllDogs(){
        var_dump($dogs);
    }
}

echo "start";
$z = new Zoo("test_zoo");
$z->addDog("blackie","black");
$z->getAllDogs();
```

The code above outputs  :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Dog' not found in C:\wamp\www\Zoo.php on line 13
```

I'd like to know what's wrong with the code above and how creating an object instance within another object should be done in PHP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to include dog.php in zoo.php so that the class will be available when called. You may want to look into auto-loading classes - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gues you are not including Dog class.

```
<?php
include "Dog.php";

class Zoo {
/* ... */
}
```

Or you can use [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to auto include any class by default.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about OOP. Just you forgot to include Dog file to use it you Zoo class :

```
<?php

include 'Dog.php'; // or whatever path   

class Zoo { ...
```

Everything else should be ok and seems to be a good use of PHP OOP btw. :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included your `Dog.php` in your `Zoo.php`. Therefore you can't create an new instance.

Just above class Zoo add this:

```
include("Dog.php");
class Zoo {
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to return function .
Three mistakes here, u'll see all of them in my code . Constructer nothing return , behave like void , so we need a method that returns dog specification.If you wanna use the classes in separate file, so u've to use php method that  "include" or "require" or "require_once"  etc ( see the difference of this method)

```
<?php 

class Dog {
    private $name;
    private $color;

    public function __construct($name,$color) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->color = $color;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getColor(){
        return $this->color;
    }
    public function getDogs(){
        return array("name"=>$this->name,"color"=>$this->color);

    }
}


class Zoo extends Dog{
    private $name;
    private $dogs=array();

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $dogs = array();
    }

    public function addDog($dogName,$dogColor){
        $dog = new Dog($dogName,$dogColor);
        array_push($this->dogs,$dog->getDogs());
    }

    public function getAllDogs(){
        var_dump($this->dogs);
    }
}

echo "start";
$z = new Zoo("test_zoo");
$z->addDog("blackie","black");

$z->getAllDogs();
?>
```